# Excel - Search contents of cells in an area (between two specific strings)

Tags: excel, search

I'm not sure it's possible to do this on Excel, but I'll explain the problem here.

I have a file with 60.000 rows and its data is displayed as follows:

T1 T2 T3 T4 T5

X X X X Y

X X X X X

X X X X X

T1 T2 T3 T4 T5

X X X X X

X X X X X

T1 T2 T3 T4 T5

X X X X X

X X X X Y

X X X X X

I want to search a specific column (this case, the last) for a specific string "Y".

If a "Y" isn't found in between the headers, the header and the rest of the content is deleted and it continues searching till the next header.

The output would be:

T1 T2 T3 T4 T5

X X X X Y

X X X X X

X X X X X

T1 T2 T3 T4 T5

X X X X X

X X X X Y

X X X X X

The headers are exactly the same and static throughout the file, so I was thinking of using them as reference.

Is it possible to do so?
If so, how?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an array formula method...

1. With your example data in `A1:E11` select `F1:F11` and enter this formula with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER:

   ```
   =LOOKUP(ROW(E1:E11),ROW(E1:E11)/(E1:E11="T5"),FREQUENCY(IF(E1:E11="Y",-ROW(E1:E11)),IF(E1:E11="T5",-ROW(E1:E11),0)))
   ```
2. You can then paste values and filter for rows containing `0` and delete these rows.

*Note*: The formula returns the count of rows that contain a `Y` between the headings. Copying data down around 60,000 rows and updating the formula takes only a few seconds to recalculate.

**Snapshot**

[image]

Comment: I can't make it work. I think I'm missing soemthing, but can't figure out what.. It's returning "#VALUE!" when it's not an Y and "NA" when it finds it. Still, how will I be able to delete the content automatically? Wouldn't I need to go one by one by using this? `=LOOKUP(ROW(L1:L59911);ROW(L1:L59911)/(L1:L59911="T5");FREQUENCY(IF(L1:L59911="Y";-ROW(L1:L59911));IF(L1:L59911="T5";-ROW(L1:L59911);0)))`

Comment: Your formula looks ok but make sure to enter in the entire range `M1:M59911` at once by pressing CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER as in the snapshot. An alternative to deleting rows as in step 2 above, is to just deselect `0` from the filter so the rows to remove are hidden, then you can copy and paste the data to a new sheet without the hidden rows.

Comment: Ah right. But the issue is that I need to keep all the info inbetween the headers, not just the specific row that has the "Y". If a row has a "Y" I want to keep all the info that goes from its header to the next one. I'm still trying to figure the best way to do it, but with little success

Comment: I may be misunderstanding but doesn't this method keep all info between headers. In the screenshot all rows between headers are marked as `1` if there is a `Y` somewhere in between.

Comment: I am at work right now and the image isn't showing up, but from what you said it sounds exactly what I want. I am getting there, I think. But I think I may have a wrong semicolon or colon somewhere, because I am getting only 0's.. On your original code there were only colons and maybe I wrote it wrong. This is what I have `=LOOKUP(ROW(L1:L53824);ROW(L1:L53824)/(L1:L53824="Ft/Nc");FREQUENCY(IF(L1:L53824="‌​A";-ROW(L1:L53824));IF(L1:L53824="Ft/Nc";-ROW(L1:L53824);0)))` . Am I missing something? Thank you very much, you're being extremely helpful!

Comment: Ah, it's working!! I had an en extra (hidden) space on one of the strings, from when I copied! Thank you so much, once more!

Comment: Glad this worked for you - persistence pays off :) And yes, copying your first formula and pasting into the immediate window of the VBE (alt+F11), shows the hidden character as "?Y" instead of "Y".

Comment: !(http://i.imgur.com/mWFzd.png)  I'm trying to take this a step further, by using an array like you suggested, but with no success.. lol I'm trying to do the following: if it finds a letter "A" in the 3rd column, sum all the values of the 2nd column (that are in the same line as the "A"), but, between the headers is a single range (like before). I've tried using `SUM((B1:B13)*(A1:A13="54341")*(C1:C13="A"))`, as well as sumifs and whatnot but I'm not sure how to do it. I reckon it should be something easy, but I've been trying many combinations and still haven't got it =/

Comment: Can you start a new thread for this as it is a different sort of problem? You want to avoid filling down repetitive formulas on large datasets as it can cause the sheet to grind to a halt. If there are no gaps between headings in the sum column you might be able to filter for the column headings and use the Autosum tool.

Comment: I'd just add that a pivot table might be a good option for your follow up question.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I did that actually, but I still have too much information. I need to narrow it down first, so the PivotTable doesn't have so many options. But maybe I can do that using pivottables themselves. I'll play around with it :p